# Incomplete Crash Report from Google

Tags: android, google-play, crash-reports

I have a crash report from Google showing this:

[image: Google crash report]

Whereas in logcat, I would see something like this:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.myscrap, PID: 1929
android.app.RemoteServiceException: Context.startForegroundService() did not then call Service.startForeground()
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1775)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Why do I not see the `Context.startForegroundService() did not then call Service.startForeground()` part in Google's crash report? I would think this is an essential part of the log.

Answer (score 0):

It takes time to see recent occurring crash in Google play dashboard. Here you're seeing two different crash logs of two different crashes. To find same crash in Google dashboard Apply filters like duration(date) and device branding to find your crash.

Also better to use Firebase Crashlytics for crash reporting in your app.

Comment: Actually, I've started using Firebase Crashlytics specifically because of this issue last month.